# How do I install Samba on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, samba

I have just downloaded the samba-3.6.1.tar.gz file from the Samba website and want to install Samba on my RedHat Linux machine, I have extracted the contents of the samba-3.6.1.tar.gz folder but havent a clue what to do now, is there an RPM file buried in there somewhere I can run?

Comment: normally on RHEL or Fedora, you simply do `yum install samba`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you downloaded the Samba source, and that's not what you want right now.  Use `yum install samba`.  That will find the correct RPM for your machine on a RedHat (or other trusted) server, download it, and install it for you.  If `yum` gives you a message about not having permissions, use `sudo yum install samba`.  If that says `sudo: command not found`, type `su` to switch to the root user, then `yum install sudo samba`.  Remember to log out of root (`logout` or `ctrl-d`) as soon as you can; you shouldn't do more as root than you need to.

Answer (score 0):

My RedHat is not registered,

```
# yum install samba
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use su
bscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
No package samba available.
Nothing to do
```

Is there a way to install without the yum command, like the question above "is there an RPM file buried in there somewhere I can run?"

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use [RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) and not [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)? As far as I know, you have to pay for RHEL updates.